# PostgreSQL: create table with unique timestamp for all rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, crud

I have a record of users' trips with begin/end positions and time in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE trips(id integer, start_timestamp timestamp with time zone, 
                   session_id integer, start_lat double precision,
                   start_lon double precision, end_lat double precision, 
                   end_lon double precision, mode integer);

INSERT INTO trips (id, start_timestamp, session_id, start_lat,start_lon,end_lat,end_lon,mode)
VALUES (563097015,'2017-05-20 17:47:12+01', 128618, 41.1783308,-8.5949878, 41.1784478, -8.5948463, 0),
 (563097013, '2017-05-20 17:45:29+01', 128618, 41.1781344, -8.5951169, 41.1782919, -8.5950689,  0),
 (563097011, '2017-05-20 17:43:41+01', 128618, 41.1781196, -8.5954075, 41.1782139, -8.5950689,  0),
 (563097009, '2017-05-20 17:41:48+01', 128618, 41.1782497,  -8.595197, 41.1781101, -8.5954124,  0),
 (563097003, '2017-05-20 17:10:29+01', 128618, 41.1832512, -8.6081606, 41.1782561, -8.5950259,  0)
```

And in the second table is the records of raw gps traces for all the trips similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE gps_traces (session_id integer, seconds integer, lat double precision,
                         lon double precision, speed double precision);

INSERT INTO gps_traces (session_id, seconds , lat , lon , speed )
VALUES (128618,1495296443,41.1844471,-8.6065158,1.35148),
     (128618,1495296444,41.1844482,-8.6065303,1.28004),
     (128618,1495296445,41.1844572,-8.6065503,1.46086),
     (128618,1495296446,41.1844541,-8.6065691,1.23),
     (128618,1495296446,41.1844589,-8.6065861, 1.22919),
     (128618,1495296447,41.1844587, -8.6066043, 1.30188),
     (128618, 1495296448, 41.1844604, -8.6066261, 1.43126),
     (128618, 1495296449, 41.184471, -8.6066412, 1.55003),
     (128618,1495296450, 41.1844715, -8.6066572, 1.29062),
     (128618,1495296450, 41.1844707, -8.6066736,  1.3618)
```

From this I want to create a new table `mytable` containing GPS joining these tables on `session_id`, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS SELECT id, seconds, lat, lon, speed, mode
FROM trips t
JOIN gps_traces g
ON t.session_id=g.session_id
```

However, in the new table, I want to ensure that for rows recorded twice at same unix timestamp in a trip, only only is selected into my new table. For example in this case:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 563097003; 
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+---------+------+
|    id     |  seconds   |    lat     |    lon     |  speed  | mode |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+---------+------+
| 563097003 | 1495296443 | 41.1844471 | -8.6065158 | 1.35148 |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296444 | 41.1844482 | -8.6065303 | 1.28004 |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296445 | 41.1844572 | -8.6065503 | 1.46086 |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296446 | 41.1844541 | -8.6065691 | 1.23    |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296446 | 41.1844589 | -8.6065861 | 1.22919 |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296447 | 41.1844587 | -8.6066043 | 1.30188 |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296448 | 41.1844604 | -8.6066261 | 1.43126 |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296449 | 41.184471  | -8.6066412 | 1.55003 |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296450 | 41.1844715 | -8.6066572 | 1.29062 |    0 |
| 563097003 | 1495296450 | 41.1844707 | -8.6066736 | 1.3618  |    0 |
| 10 rows   |            |            |            |         |      |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+---------+------+
```

Column `seconds` is the Unix timestamp. As shown, we can see rows having  more than 1 unique  timestamp count at `1495296446` and `1495296450`.  I would like to ensure that for each trip, records are selected into the new table with unique timestamp (so in the case above, only one recorded should selected into the new table). I illustrate that in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7b8db358385be016f82cd43660a6d10e).

**EDIT**

Expected output:

```
    +-----------+------------+------------+------------+---------+------+
    |    id     |  seconds   |    lat     |    lon     |  speed  | mode |
    +-----------+------------+------------+------------+---------+------+
    | 563097003 | 1495296443 | 41.1844471 | -8.6065158 | 1.35148 |    0 |
    | 563097003 | 1495296444 | 41.1844482 | -8.6065303 | 1.28004 |    0 |
    | 563097003 | 1495296445 | 41.1844572 | -8.6065503 | 1.46086 |    0 |
    | 563097003 | 1495296446 | 41.1844541 | -8.6065691 | 1.23    |    0 |
    | 563097003 | 1495296447 | 41.1844587 | -8.6066043 | 1.30188 |    0 |
    | 563097003 | 1495296448 | 41.1844604 | -8.6066261 | 1.43126 |    0 |
    | 563097003 | 1495296449 | 41.184471  | -8.6066412 | 1.55003 |    0 |
    | 563097003 | 1495296450 | 41.1844715 | -8.6066572 | 1.29062 |    0 |
    | 8 rows    |            |            |            |         |      |
    +-----------+------------+------------+------------+---------+------+
```

Comment: "_only one recorded should selected_" The main question here: which one exactly?

Comment: @Abelisto For example in the expected answer table, the first records for timestamp `1495296446` and `1495296450` were selected. In the new table, `id= 563097003` now has 8 rows, not 10.

Comment: I meant: those rows with the duplicated `seconds` values differs only by `lat/lon/speed`. How do you make decision which one should be in the final data?

Comment: To choose only the first row encountered irrespective of `lat/lon/speed` values.

Comment: @Abelisto Is there a way to update the created table, by somehow checking where a trip `id` having a unique count of  `seconds` greater than one so the second is deleted?

Comment: There is the fixed Gordon's answer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8e14d3888422a135dc465effe0e657dc

Comment: Perfect, many thanks.

Comment: Good luck! ) PS: Note that the "_first row encountered_" without any significant ordering means "random". So, probably, you need to add `g.ctid desc` to `order by` clause to get the last inserted rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.session_id, seconds) id, seconds, lat, lon, speed, mode
    FROM trips t JOIN
         gps_traces g
         ON t.session_id = g.session_id
    ORDER BY t.session_id, seconds;
```

Note:  I would expect you to include `session_id` in the new table as well.

Thanks to @Abelisto, it turns out that the following modification to this answer works as intended.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, seconds)id, 
 seconds, lat, lon, speed, mode
FROM trips t
JOIN gps_traces g
ON t.session_id=g.session_id
ORDER BY id, seconds
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0274aa6bc3a4694338e3b410bd50183) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: ERROR:  `column reference "session_id" is ambiguous
LINE 2:     SELECT DISTINCT ON (session_id, seconds) id, seconds, la..`

Comment: @super_ask . . . That should be qualified.

Comment: But that gives only two rows instead of all rows as in the question without duplicate in `seconds`

Comment: Strange, it works on `SELECT DISTINCT ON (..)` b ut not on `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT DISTINCT ON (..)` So for example only two rows were returned for `id=563097003`. This id should have eight rows.